# Xamarin Forms Webview API jqXHR status 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Having some issues with a **API call from Xamarin Forms (iOS)**.
My app loads local html and java script files from the Resources directory and as far as I can tell, it all loads as expected.

My issue is when the javascript (onclick) executes an **$.ajax** call. **(BTW jquery is defiantly loading correctly).**

Due to not having console when looking at the webview in an iPhone simulator, all I can do is alert a heap of the error messages. My ajax request is returning a stats code of 0 *(Which I am pretty sure means no connection)*

So my first question is, do I need to explicitly tell the iOS app it can use the internet and if so, is that something I set in the AppDelegate file?

Second if that is not the case, has anyone come across this issue before? I read something that suggested I needed to **REMOVE** my CORS headers from my ajax calls which yielded no improvement of the issue.

The project setup **C# Library (Portable)** and **iOS Xamarin Forms** application.

**iOS (AppDelegate.cs)**

```
{
    [Register ("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : 
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate // superclass new in 1.3
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init ();

            LoadApplication (new App ());  // method is new in 1.3

            return base.FinishedLaunching (app, options);
        }
    }
}
```

**Portable (App.cs)**

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App ()
    {
        var browser = new BaseUrlWebView();
        var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
        htmlSource.Html = @"<html>
                            <head>
                                <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' />      
                                <link rel='stylesheet'href='assets/css/login.css' />      
                            </head> 
                            <body>
                                <div id ='wrapper'>
                                    <section id ='sidebar'>
                                        <section>
                                            <ul class='actions vertical'>
                                                <li><input type='text' name='Username' id='txtUsername'></li>
                                                <li><input type='text' name='Password' id='txtPassword'></li>
                                            </ul>                       
                                        </section>
                                        <section>
                                            <ul class='actions vertical'>
                                                <li><a class='button big fit' onclick='btnClicked()'>Log In</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </section>
                                    </section>
                                </div>
                                    <script src ='assets/js/jquery.min.js' ></script>
                                    <script src ='js/login.js'></script>
                            </body>
                        </html>";

        htmlSource.BaseUrl = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();           
        browser.Source = htmlSource;
        MainPage = new ContentPage { Content = browser };

    }
}
```

Pulling this code locally into a html file and using the same javascript in xampp works fine.

> UPDATE

After adding some JS to ping my API I can confirm that it can reach it. So the issue must be that the app isn't waiting for the ajax call to complete? Or something else might be happening deep down in the guts of how the iOS webview works.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out, since iOS 9 http:// is not allowed in a ajax request, it must be secured with https://

In the info.plist I added the API site as a trusted site and it all came good.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>myapi.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.0</string>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```